# htaccess - How to exclude one folder of the restricted area

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess looks like that:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

Now I want to exclude the folder "test" from the restricted area, I tried to add this:

```
<Directory /var/www/test/*/>
  Allow from all 
  Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

But then I get a 500 Internal Server Error. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Directory>` isn't allowed in .htaccess actually.

You can resolve it by creating a `/test/.htaccess` with this 1 line:

```
Satisfy any
```